# Determine if its night time

Tags: php, date, datetime

Our restaurant is open til 3:00 am on friday and monday. I have build a website/webshop for odering. After a user typs a zipcode it gets the day for ex monday. then it gets the opening and closing times for monday. if the store is open you can order.

The problem is that if you typ your zipcode after 0:00 on a friday the shop will show closed because the "system" thinks its saturday so it grabs the closing time for saturday. i use $day = date("l"); to get the day.

No this is al logical because after 0:00 on a friday is saturday.. but i need some workaround to let the system know that if i type a zipcode on friday after 0:00 (so on saturday) the system gets the friday closing times from the database and not the saturday ones.

What is the best way to approach this ?

Comment: You need to show code you tried. Like this we can tell you check if current hours are between 0 and 3 and day is Saturday or Tuesday, and read closing time of previous date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to along with checking the day is to check the time. If it's before the closing time of yesterday then show yesterday's closing time. Otherwise show today's opening time. Something like this:

```
// If it's before 5am set time to yesterday.
if((int)date('G') < 5) {
    $time = time();
} else {
    $time = strtotime('-1 day');
}
$day = date('N', $time);
```

Comment: ok this is good, but.. i want it like this if its later then 0:00 or earlier then 3:00 then show the day of before. But your script shows day 7 now... but its monday so i dont know why...

Comment: I've set it for if it's less than 5, just change the in the if statement to a 3 if you want earlier than 3. I also used the days from date, so Monday is day 1 and Sunday is day 7, that might not be the way you had done it. If not you need to adjust the code to suit.